# Postgres 9.2 pg_largeobject tablespace

Tags: postgresql, centos, postgresql-9.2

I am currently moving some data around and I am running into an interesting issue.

I have a CentOS server (6.3) up and running with Postgres 9.2 on a server with limited built in disk space; however, I do have a large amount of extremely reliable external network disk space available.

I have set the tablespace to a directory on this storage devise for my database and everything seems to be working well, until...

I realized that I have a large amount of BLOB data that needs to be stored in `pg_largeobject`.

I have been goggling how to set the tablespace of `pg_largeobject` and I did find [some results](https://www.google.com/search?q=postgres%20alter%20pg_catalog%20tablespace&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_rn=6&gs_ri=psy-ab&gs_mss=postgres%20alter%20pg_largeobjec%20tablespace&tok=ChZqJcfhL2IDlxWeh1gcSg&pq=postgres%20alter%20pg_catalog%20tablespace&cp=29&gs_id=3ci&xhr=t&q=postgres%20alter%20pg_largeobject%20tablespace&es_nrs=true&pf=p&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&oq=postgres%20alter%20pg_largeobject%20tablespace&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43828540,d.b2I&fp=81c21314fc32b652&biw=1532&bih=1280), but they are horribly out dated.

I did find [one article](http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-hackers/09a5669m7s/moving-system-catalogs-to-another-tablespace) that looks promising, but I'm hesitant because the thread also references that things will/should have changed.

**I have two questions...**

1. In an ideal world, I would like to move all of postgres (including `pg_largeobject`) onto this external storage for ease of maintenance. Is this possible?
2. If not, how can I get `pg_largeobject` to use my network storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you alluded to, your best bet is to move the entirety of PostgreSQL onto the remote storage, assuming that storage uses a reliable file network block device like iSCSI, ATAoE or NBD. I wouldn't recommend running Pg on NFS, and running it on CIFS/SMBFS just won't work.

Just:

- Make a backup
- Take a note of the output of `SHOW data_directory;` in `psql`
- Shut PostgreSQL down
- Move the data directory (the folder containing `pg_xlog`, `pg_clog`, etc) to the remote storage
- Adjust the permissions on the parent directories for the datadir's new location to make sure the `postgres` user, `postgres`, group or `others` permissions block has at least `execute` on each parent directory so it can traverse the tree.
- Adjust your system startup scripts to set the new location as the PostgreSQL datadir *or* symlink the old datadir location (output by `SHOW data_directory`) to the new location.
- Start PostgreSQL

Unfortunately, different systems and packages find the datadir different ways. Debian/Ubuntu use pg_wrapper, for example.

Comment: thanks for the quick response... I don't see anything in the `/etc/sysconfig/pgsql/` directory... where else could I find it? Also, is it possible to do a fresh install of postgres directly to the remote location?

Comment: @losthorse How did you install PostgreSQL? What packages are you using?

Comment: I followed the tutorial found here http://people.planetpostgresql.org/devrim/index.php?/archives/70-How-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.2-on-RHELCentOSScientific-Linux-5-and-6.html and installed the package directly.

Comment: @losthorse OK, so you're using the PGDG RPMs. It looks like the datadir isn't configurable in them, so see updated answer.

Comment: Okay, I found the directory that holds the files you mentioned... I don't mind following the instructions you provided, but if possible, I would rather go with a fresh install. I don't mind adding the repo and using yum if that would give me ability to set a destination directory... part of what I am trying to avoid is having to keep the log files on the server in sync with the records on the external storage when performing backups.

Comment: @losthorse The PGDG RPMs don't let you set the datadir, so a reinstall won't change anything. Just symlink the *whole* datadir, including `pg_xlog`, `pg_clog`, etc. You can symlink the PostgreSQL log files to the same storage if you want, or set the logging parameters in `postgresql.conf` so it writes the log files where you want it to.

Comment: @losthorse Just to be clear, symlink the directory *containing* `pg_xlog`, `pg_clog`, `base`, etc, don't add individual symlinks for each. Remember that the whole datadir needs to be kept in sync; if you lose say your `pg_clog` you've lost the whole database.